# Haystack Faceted: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'facet_fields'

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, faceted-search

While enjoying my first results with haystack 2.4.1 (Django 1.8), I have to admit that I'm having a hard time on learning it. The documentation is sometimes incomplete, and some features have to few examples.

Faceted search is one of them.

I'm following the [documentation](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.4.1/faceting.html), and at the url.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('haystack.views',
    url(r'^$', FacetedSearchView(form_class=FacetedSearchForm, facet_fields=['author']), name='haystack_search'),
)
```

I'm getting the following error:

> **TypeError at /tag_analytics/faceted_search/**
>
> *__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'facet_fields'*

Looks like the FacetSearchView is not accepting the `facet_fields` argument, which took me to version 2.4.0, when the right way to do this was

```
FacetedSearchView(form_class=FacetedSearchForm, searchqueryset=sqs)
```

Although I'm sure my version is 2.4.1, I tried this option, and got a

> **TypeError at /tag_analytics/faceted_search/**
>
> *slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method*

Thanks in advance for any clues!

the best,
alan

Comment: I've got a "solution" which I doubt is the right one, since it would mean that the documentation is completely wrong. Anyway, on url.py I replaced `from haystack.views import FacetedSearchView` with `from haystack.generic_views import FacetedSearchView`, and `FacetedSearchView(form_class=FacetedSearchForm, facet_fields=['author'])` with `FacetedSearchView.as_view(form_class=FacetedSearchForm, facet_fields=['author'],template_name='search.html', context_object_name='page_object')` . It works, but I still wanted to understand the what was the problem!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation is just wrong, and confusing. You cannot pass `facet_fields` to the constructor for `FacetedSearchView`.

The approach you have taken is correct although rather than put all those arguments in the `url` definition, you should create your own view - something like this:

```
# tag_analytics/views.py
from haystack.generic_views import FacetedSearchView as BaseFacetedSearchView

# Now create your own that subclasses the base view
class FacetedSearchView(BaseFacetedSearchView):
    form_class = FacetedSearchForm
    facet_fields = ['author']
    template_name = 'search.html'
    context_object_name = 'page_object'

    # ... Any other custom methods etc
```

Then in `urls.py`:

```
from tag_analytics.views import FacetedSearchView
#...
url(r'^$', FacetedSearchView.as_view(), name='haystack_search'),
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Just corrected a small typo, and its working well now!

Comment: @AlanTygel i got an error: name 'FacetedSearchForm' is not defined with this answer. If using urls.py variant no errors, but also no results, don't know why

Comment: @VicNicethemer you have to import it: `from haystack.forms import FacetedSearchForm`. This was assumed in the OPs question.

Comment: @solarissmoke imported - no no results, no facets. Index rebuilt, results normally appear in simple view

Comment: @VicNicethemer suggest you ask a new question then that details your problem.

Comment: @VicNicethemer have you solved the issue of empty results?

Comment: @VicNicethemer I have solved it, you can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49220132/django-haysteck-facetedsearchview-returning-empty-results/49362214#49362214