# Django-Haystack Faceting Initial Set up

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

Haystack 2.4.1 (Django 1.9)

I’m having trouble with faceted search.

I tried to follow the example from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36958377/haystack-faceted-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-facet-fields) recent Stack Overflow answer, but it still isn't working.

From a Searchapp

```
#search/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from haystack.forms import FacetedSearchForm
from haystack.generic_views import FacetedSearchView as BaseFacetedSearchView

class FacetedSearchView(BaseFacetedSearchView):
        form_class = FacetedSearchForm
        facet_fields = ['categories']
    template_name = 'search/search.html'
    context_object_name = 'page_object'

#urls.py
from haystack.forms import FacetedSearchForm
from search.views import FacetedSearchView
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet

urlpatterns += patterns('haystack.views',
    url(r'^search/', FacetedSearchView.as_view(), name='haystack_search'),
)
```

**I’d appreciate any help you guys can provide.  I’m at my wits end on this one.**

I am using the template from the Haystack documentation.

```
{% if query %}
    <!-- Begin faceting. -->
    <h2>By Category</h2>

    {{ self.get_facets }}

    <div>
        <dl>
            {% if facets.fields.category %}
                <dt>category</dt>
                {# Provide only the top 5 categories #}
                {% for category in facets.fields.categories|slice:":5" %}
                    <dd><a href="{{ request.get_full_path }}&amp;selected_facets=category_exact:{{ category.0|urlencode }}">{{ category.0 }}</a> ({{ category.1 }})</dd>
                {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                <p>No category facets.</p>
            {% endif %}
        </dl>
    </div>
    <!-- End faceting -->

    <!-- Display results... -->
    {% for result in page_object %}
        <div class="search_result">
            <h3><a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object.title }}</a></h3>

            <p>{{ result.object.body|truncatewords:80 }}</p>
        </div>
    {% empty %}
        <p>Sorry, no results found.</p>
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

Comment: I answered the issue you refer to in step 1 in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36958377/haystack-faceted-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-facet-fields/36962796#36962796). The Haystack documentation is broken.

Comment: thanks for the response solarissmoke.  i tried to follow your changes, but still having trouble.  any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting an error or just no facets appearing? Have you rebuilt the search index?

Comment: I'm not getting any error, there are just no facets appearing and no regular search results found.  When I run sqs.facet_counts() in the shell, the output is fine.  However, when I run a search through my search form, I get "no category facets" and "sorry, no results found" for the display results.  

I have rebuilt the search index, but there wasn't any change.  

Thanks again for your help, solarissmoke.

Comment: Sounds like a template context issue. For the search results, please try `{% for result in object_list %}` instead of what you currently have and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: i think you're right about it being a template context issue.  i tried changing to object_list, but didn't make any difference though.

Comment: @jake - can you please respond how did you solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page is not in context. Use object_list directly to access the objects.

Otherwise, if you want to follow along the websites official tutorial, just use this in your urls.py:

```
url(r'^search/', FacetedSearchView(form_class=FacetedSearchForm, searchqueryset = SearchQuerySet().facet('author')), name='haystack_search)
```

instead of :

```
url(r'^search/', FacetedSearchView(form_class=FacetedSearchForm, selected_facets=['author'] , name='haystack_search).
```

Hope this helps sombody :)