# django haysteck FacetedSearchView returning empty results?

Tags: django, django-haystack

I'm using Django haystack FacetedSearchView my `views.py`:

```
from haystack.generic_views import FacetedSearchView as BaseFacetedSearchView
class FacetedSearchView(BaseFacetedSearchView):
    template_name = 'test.html'
    facet_fields = ['source']
```

and in `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^search', FacetedSearchView.as_view(), name='haystack_search')
```

and in test.html I'm rendering the facets.

When I issue a request, the content of the `factes` context object is empty dict. but I think it should return all the I specified facets in `facets_fields`, and when I append `q` parameter to the request's querystring (with any value) it returns result but with zero document. is it neccessary to provide the `q` parameter? and with which value?

Answer (score 0):

to solve the issue on need to override the search method of FacetedSearchForm, because the original implementation assumes a query 'q' but faceting needs only `facet_fields` to work.

```
from haystack.forms import FacetedSearchForm as BaseFacetedSearchForm
from haystack.generic_views import FacetedSearchView as BaseFacetedSearchView
class FacetedSearchForm(BaseFacetedSearchForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.selected_facets = kwargs.pop("selected_facets", [])
        super(FacetedSearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def search(self):
        if not self.is_valid():
            return self.no_query_found()

        sqs = self.searchqueryset
        # We need to process each facet to ensure that the field name and the
        # value are quoted correctly and separately:
        for facet in self.selected_facets:
            if ":" not in facet:
                continue
            field, value = facet.split(":", 1)

            if value:
                sqs = sqs.narrow(u'%s:"%s"' % (field, sqs.query.clean(value)))

        if self.load_all:
            sqs = sqs.load_all()

        return sqs

class FacetedSearchView(BaseFacetedSearchView):
    template_name = 'facets.html'
    facet_fields = []
    form_class = FacetedSearchForm
```